# Pagination with JPA projection in spring boot returns just one record

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am using **pagination with native query**  on one of my sql table, because of aliases in my query I used JPA pojection and made an interface and get the fields from my DTO Class, but when I hit it using postman I get only one record instead of getting several records when I give the size more than one it results an empty object like

```
`{
     "content": [],
        "pageable": {
            "sort": {
                "empty": true,
                "sorted": false,
                "unsorted": true
            },
            "offset": 10,
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "pageSize": 10,
            "paged": true,
            "unpaged": false
        },
        "last": true,
        "totalPages": 1,
        "totalElements": 2,
        "size": 10,
        "number": 1,
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "numberOfElements": 0,
        "first": false,
        "empty": true
    }`
```

but when I give the size = 1 it returns one record , when I use the same query  in `mySql` it works fine and returns all the records as expected. can anyone tell me what is the problem with my code. My code  is stated below

[Postman Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixrgi.png)

Postman response After I provide size = 1

`

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "channel": "B",
            "userName": "asdas",
            "primaryKey": "sadasd",
            "contactNumber": "asdsa",
            "minRequestTime": "2022-12-13 10:36:45.0",
            "maxRequestTime": "2022-12-13 10:36:45.0",
            "success": "0",
            "totalHits": "4",
            "failed": "4"
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 1,
        "pageSize": 1,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "unpaged": false,
        "paged": true
    },
    "totalElements": 3,
    "totalPages": 3,
    "last": false,
    "size": 1,
    "number": 1,
    "sort": {
        "empty": true,
        "sorted": false,
        "unsorted": true
    },
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "first": false,
    "empty": false
}
```

`

Here is Mysql table, it has 28 Records

[SQL Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh7xq.png)

Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "reporting_general")
@Data
public class ReportingGeneral implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    @Column(name = "transaction_name")
    public String transactionName;
    public String username;
    @Column(name = "contact_number")
    public String contactNumber;
    public String segment;
    @Column(name = "user_type")
    public String userType;
    @Column(name = "primary_key")
    public String primaryKey;
    public String channel;
    @Column(name = "response_code")
    public String ResponseCode;
    @Column(name = "request_time")
    public Date requestTime;
    @Column(name = "response_time")
    public Date responseTime;

}
```

Interface used  for projection

```
public interface ActiveAccountReport {
    String getUserName();
    String getContactNumber();
    String getPrimaryKey();
    String getMinRequestTime();
    String getMaxRequestTime();
    String getSuccess();
    String getFailed();
    String getTotalHits();
    String getChannel();
}
```

Repository Class

```
@Repository
public interface ReportingGenRepo extends JpaRepository<ReportingGeneral, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT REPORTING_GENERAL.USERNAME AS userName, " +
            "ANY_VALUE (REPORTING_GENERAL.CONTACT_NUMBER ) AS contactNumber,ANY_VALUE (REPORTING_GENERAL.PRIMARY_KEY) AS primaryKey," +
            "MIN( REQUEST_TIME ) AS minRequestTime ,MAX( REQUEST_TIME ) AS maxRequestTime, " +
            "COUNT(IF ( RESPONSE_CODE = '1', 1, NULL )) AS success,COUNT(IF " +
            "( RESPONSE_CODE != '1', 1, NULL )) AS failed,COUNT(*) AS totalHits,CHANNEL as channel" +
            " FROM REPORTING_GENERAL WHERE " +
            " REPORTING_GENERAL.ID > 0 AND CHANNEL in ?3 AND (REPORTING_GENERAL.REQUEST_TIME  BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)" +
            "GROUP BY channel, username",

            countQuery = "SELECT count(*) FROM REPORTING_GENERAL WHERE " +
                    " REPORTING_GENERAL.ID > 0 AND CHANNEL in ?3 AND (REPORTING_GENERAL.REQUEST_TIME  BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2)" +
                    "GROUP BY channel, username", nativeQuery = true)
    public Page<ActiveAccountReport> getActiveAccountReportFilters(
            LocalDateTime startDate,
            LocalDateTime endDate,
            List<Character> channel,
            Pageable pageable);
}
```

Service Class

```
@Service
public class ReportingGenService {
    @Autowired
    private ReportingGenRepo reportingGenRepo;

    public Page<ActiveAccountReport> paginatedActiveAccountReports(ActiveAccountRequest activeAccountRequest,
                                                   Integer page,Integer size) {

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page,size);
        Page<ActiveAccountReport> activeAccountReports = reportingGenRepo
          .getActiveAccountReportFilters(activeAccountRequest.getStartDate(),
                activeAccountRequest.getEndDate(),activeAccountRequest.getChannel(),pageable);

        return activeAccountReports;
    }


}
```

Controller Class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/repo")
public class ReportingGenController {
    @Autowired
    private ReportingGenService reportingGenService;

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public Page<ActiveAccountReport> findAll(@RequestBody ActiveAccountRequest activeAccountRequest,
                                   @RequestParam(value = "page",defaultValue = "0") Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "size",defaultValue = "1") Integer size){
        return reportingGenService.paginatedActiveAccountReports(activeAccountRequest,page,size);

    }
}
```

Can Anyone Help please

Answer (score 0):

You are setting request param variable value for page index 1 and total records 1 that's why it returns one record. You can set 5 or more after that you will get different result.

```
Your postman request : http://localhost:1111/repo/get?page=1&size=1
Try this request     : http://localhost:1111/repo/get?page=1&size=10
```

Comment: Sorry I think that's not the problem, when I give the size more than one like you stated `http://localhost:1111/repo/get?page=1&size=10` , It results an empty result. like ` '{
    "content": [],
    "pageable": {
        "sort": {
            "empty": true,
            "sorted": false,
            "unsorted": true
        },
        "offset": 10,
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "pageSize": 10,
        "paged": true,
        "unpaged": false
    },
    "last": true,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 2,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 1,
   
}``

Comment: I've updated my question, please review it

Comment: You can use limit into native query for pagination...!! Try it. Limit will always gives you records based on limit you set into your query.

Comment: like this for example? `My query*.... limit 5,native query=true`

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Try with 0 index means first page and after that 10 records.